# How to install GNOME desktop on linux (CENTOS)

Tags: linux, installation, gnome, centos

How to install GNOME desktop on linux (CENTOS).I would appreciate detailed steps as I am a linux newbie.

Comment: This question is better asked on serverfault.com

Comment: Well, superuser actually...

Comment: it has been asked on serverfault, and downvoted there too. http://serverfault.com/questions/40901/how-to-install-gnome-desktop-on-linux-centos

Comment: Vow; people are very religious here about the kind of questions. I am a developer and needed this environment to figure our some issue and looks like it is treated like crime here and also somebody went ahead checked serverfault too for my activity trace;).

Answer (score 5):

Login as superuser and type:

```
 yum groupinstall "X Window System" "GNOME Desktop Environment"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use yum as indicated [here](http://mmg007.wordpress.com/2006/11/05/installing-gnome-desktop-on-centosrhfc-server-installation/) and [here](http://www.gizmola.com/blog/archives/74-Install-Xwindows-and-Gnome-on-Centos-with-Yum.html).

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this: `yum install @x11 @desktop`

Answer (score 0):

try this `yum install gnome-desktop`

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) could be improved by explaining *why/how* your solution fixes/addresses the OPs question.

Comment: I get an error message `No package gnome-desktop available`